# SnmpExtensionInit not invoked

Tags: winapi, dll, snmp, dllexport

I am trying to add an extension to the Windows SNMP agent and have followed the sketchy documentation that is available.  The dll has been built and the two entries have been placed into the registry.  Restarting the SNMP service seems to load the DLL.  DllMain is called with the following reasons: DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, DLL_THREAD_ATTACH, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.  But SnmpExtensionInit never seems to get called.  Any ideas?  TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give the declaration of your `SnmpExtensionInit`. Sorry it's in french, but try your DLL with [slxSNMPInfo](http://www.silogix.fr/Outils/slxsnmpinfo.aspx) tool. This tool just load your DLL and try to invoke `SnmpExtensionInit`.

---

Edited (after your comment)

`"Err SNMP DLL not detected !"` in [slwSNMPInfo.exe](http://www.silogix.fr/Outils/slxsnmpinfo.aspx) attest that your DLL does not export "SnmpExtensionInit" function. You can also verify this with [Dependency Walker tool](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

To export correctly your functions in a Windows DLL you can use a *definition file* ([a .def file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) like this :

```
LIBRARY YOUR-DLL-NAME

DESCRIPTION 'SNMP Extension Agent for Windows NT.'

SEGMENTS
  _TEXT      PRELOAD
  INIT_TEXT  PRELOAD

HEAPSIZE  1024

EXPORTS
  SnmpExtensionInit
  SnmpExtensionTrap
  SnmpExtensionQuery
```

Or you can change your functions déclarations (all the three)

```
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL SnmpExtensionInit (DWORD dwTimeZeroReference,
                                              HANDLE *hPollForTrapEvent,
                                              AsnObjectIdentifier *supportedView);
```

Comment: BOOL WINAPI SnmpExtensionInit(

Comment: BOOL WINAPI SnmpExtensionInit(IN DWORD dwTimeZeroReference, OUT HANDLE *hPollForTrapEvent, OUT AsnObjectIdentifier *supportedView)

Comment: Running slxSNMPInfo c:\windows\system32\my.dll returns "Err SNMP DLL not detected !"

Comment: If I do this, I get inconsistent function signatures.  Is there any recent documentation on this since anything I could find was at least 5-6 years old?  What snmp.h should I be using?  I have found some in the various Windows Resource Kits.

Comment: I modified both my code and the declarations in snmp.h for the three
functions and was then able to get SlxSNMPINfo to at least recognize
that my DLL had the correct signature for SnmpExtensionInit.  But when
I run it, I get the following output before it crashes:

SlxSNMPInfo found following OID(s) :
0.-1.4194304.2432656.131072.0.1376256.2090337824.2089816064.2089816288.1.2118199
664.0.0.0.0.2090337760.1023.0.2137980928.2137980928.2137982600.2147155968.214722
5600.2147295232.1.0.0.127631360.-6035.1048576.8192.65536.4096.7.16

Vers 1.0 Copyright 2011 - Jean Paul Blanc/Silogix

Comment: For reference, here's a snippet from my code from SnmpExtensionInit
that sets the OID node point:

UINT OID_Prefix[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 12 };
AsnObjectIdentifier MIB_OidPrefix = { OID_SIZEOF(OID_Prefix), OID_Prefix };

*supportedView = MIB_OidPrefix;

Comment: These two solutions are working nowdays with Visual Studio 2008 and .H file coming from SDK. I use "C" compiler. And I began from Microsoft Examples in 1999.

Comment: Didn't you have to modify snmp.h to make the function signatures match?

Comment: Rather than going back and forth, have you got a sample that works?

Comment: Be careful, my tool can be a bit  buggy and perhaps don't ends correctly, Iam going to have a look.

Comment: I can give you my dll if you want it.

Comment: I d'ont change the .H, I use the Def file as given.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  Your comment about not changing the .h file made me think that I shouldn't change the definitions in the .c either which meant that it must be the .def file.  I didn't realize that the Linker had to be told to use the .def file.  Once I did that, everything worked!  Thanks again.